# want to use new headless server with VirtualBox; startx hangs at extension GLX

Tags: server, virtualbox, gui, headless

ssh'ing into the server and running `startx` yields this.

Background info that may help: I originally hooked up my monitor and keyboard directly to the box, but now wondering if there are some parameters that are populated with the  monitor that is not there anymore?

```
dumbledore@HogwartsCastle:/$ startx

X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-70-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux HogwartsCastle 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic root=/dev/mapper/HogwartsCastle--vg-root ro
Build Date: 10 December 2014  06:15:52PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.6 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.6.log", Time: Sat Jan 24 18:02:49 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
xf86TokenToOptinfo: table is NULL
xf86TokenToOptinfo: table is NULL
```